# A hypothetical nerve damage question

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

If a 100 pound bucket is dropped on someone's hand, what will this do to the nerves, will they get crushed, will they die? And how will this affect that person's ability to feel or move their hand?

Comment: From what height?

Comment: About 3 feet off the ground